# Vtiger CRM change event notification email template

Tags: vtiger

where i can change the email notification template to inform users.

no i hae template like this:

User Name,

Meeting with user Name
29-04-2016 2:30 PM (UTC+01:00) Sarajevo, Skopje, Warsaw, Zagreb
9-04-2016 2:35 PM (UTC+01:00) Sarajevo, Skopje, Warsaw, Zagreb
Planned
Localization:

Administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no inbuilt template defined in CRM to send the reminders / notifications of meetings. You have to customize the things as per below:

1. Open `\modules\Calendar\CalendarCommon.php`
2. Search `function getActivityDetails(`
3. You will find email body text has been written in `$list` variable. Modify the template content as per your need and save the file.

Hope it will helps to you. Cheers!